# How to Block Automounting of a Specific Drive (USB connection) With ** Three Mounted Partitions **

Tags: mount, data-recovery, fstab, automount, ddrescue

I need to block the auto mounting of a specific external drive (USB connection, by UID) that has three different mount points (partitions)?

The contents of this drive were created with ddrescue - to copy the data from a failed drive.

The drive is being auto-mounted to three locations (sdc1,sdc3, sdc4), and it is being mounted read-write (bad). I can manually remount read-only. Most of the post-ddrescue tools need to have the drive unmounted.  What is happening is the drive is being AUTOMATICALLY REMOUNTED (to the three mount points, r/w) when I exit the tools. I'm getting the new device mounting notifications - otherwise I would have never imagined this would happen.

I found instructions to block the auto-mounting of an external drive with a SINGLE mounted partition. You add an entry to fstab, using the UID.  The instructions indicate you have to enter a mount point.  But I have three mount points with this drive.  How do I do this?  Also, I would prefer to not define mounting points at all.  I should be able to just block the auto-mounting of a device, by UID, period -- where is has to be manually mounted by root.

---

Update: This **did not** work.

`/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx /media/me/ESP vfat ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
UUID=xxxx-xxxx /media/me/DIAGS vfat ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/me/WINRETOOLS ntfs ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/me/OS ntfs ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
```

Partitions 1, 3, and 4 are still being auto-mounted, as before.  (2 never was.)

Comment: 3 lines in fstab, I would guess, but to mee this appears more a matter of changing udev rules (see here https://linuxconfig.org/tutorial-on-how-to-write-basic-udev-rules-in-linux for a primer)

Comment: I saw something about using udev rules, but it was based on a block device name, or a device type, and not a UID.  I need my other external drive, which is also a 500GB Seagate Blue, to automount.  I'll start looking into whether you can use this option by UID.

Comment: Use the `noauto` parameter in /etc/fstab. See `man fstab` for more info.

Comment: @ heynnema Yes, but the drive is mounted to three mount points.  How do I add this to fstab?

Comment: Three separate fstab entires, one for each partition. The same exact line that you would use to mount it, with the exception of the noauto parameter.

Comment: What's different about the noauto parameter?

Comment: @vanadium -  UUIDs are not accessible by udev in Ubuntu.  I need my other 500GB Seagate Blue (identical drive) to automount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `man fstab` page we find the `noauto` parameter...

```
  The fourth field (fs_mntops).
          This  field  describes  the  mount  options  associated with the
          filesystem.

          It is formatted as a comma-separated list of options.   It  con‐
          tains at least the type of mount (ro or rw), plus any additional
          options appropriate to the filesystem  type  (including  perfor‐
          mance-tuning options).  For details, see mount(8) or swapon(8).

          Basic filesystem-independent options are:

          defaults
                 use  default  options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser,
                 and async.

          noauto do not mount when "mount -a"  is  given  (e.g.,  at  boot
                 time)

          user   allow a user to mount

          owner  allow device owner to mount

          comment
                 or x-<name> for use by fstab-maintaining programs

          nofail do  not  report errors for this device if it does not ex‐
                 ist.
```

Using `sudo blkid` you can easily determine the proper UUIDs to use.

You'll need to create these entries in /etc/fstab...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx /media/me/ESP vfat ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
UUID=xxxx-xxxx /media/me/DIAGS vfat ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/me/WINRETOOLS ntfs ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/me/OS ntfs ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
```

**Update #1:**

OP replaced Nautilus file manager with Thunar, and Thunar has a separate option to mount external drives. Disable that, and this all works as expected. Not a standard configuration.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102849/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-to-block-automounting-of-a-specific-drive).

Answer (score 1):

Auto-mounting was enabled in the File Manager (non-default Thunar), and this was overriding /etc/fstab.  The setting in the File Manager (Volume Management) is all-or-nothing, mount external drives automatically, or don't.  So I disabled that, and am controlling things with udev and fstab.

Comment: That would be Thunar, not Nautilus. Not a standard configuration.

Comment: Correct.  I changed to Thunar, and I don't have Nautilus on hand to check if it also has a volume management setting.

Comment: Nautilus doesn't have such an option. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `noauto` in `/etc/fstab` as in [heynnema's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199327/8822) answer worked well for me.

To make it easier to generate the needed lines, you can have `lsblk` print all the info that will be needed:

```
lsblk -o KNAME,UUID,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT
```

Or this long one-liner which gives the output expected in /etc/fstab:

```
lsblk -o KNAME,UUID,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT | perl -nle 'if (/^(sd\S+) +([-a-z0-9]{36}) +(\S+) +(.*)/) {print "# was $4\n", "UUID=$2  /tmp/$1  $3  ro,noauto,nofail 0 0"}'
```

But beware that it lists all disks with a UUID, so don't just paste it blindly into /etc/fstab...