# After modifying /etc/fstab, drives are still auto-mounting at boot time only

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

I added entries to block the partitions on an external drive (via USB) from auto-mounting at boot time.  I tried using the UUIDs, and the block names (/dev/sdc1).  (I need to be using the UUIDs.)

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/me/OS ntfs ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
```

and separately:

```
/dev/sdc4 /media/me/OS ntfs ro,noauto,nofail 0 0
```

If I manually umount the partitions, I can mount them with `sudo mount /dev/sdc3 /media/me/OS`

`sudo mount -a` does not remount the partitions.

The drive is a 500GB Seagate Blue.  Three partitions are being auto-mounted. The file explorer dialog for each is opening.  The dialogs are calling them "volumes."  This disk is a copy of a failed disk I recovered with ddrescue.

This question is based on an earlier question I asked, [How to Block Automounting of a Specific Drive (USB connection) With ** Three Mounted Partitions **](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199318/how-to-block-automounting-of-a-specific-drive-usb-connection-with-three-mou)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-mounting was enabled in the File Manager (non-standard Thunar mod), and this was overriding /etc/fstab.  The setting in the File Manager (Volume Management) is all-or-nothing, mount external drives automatically, or don't.  So I disabled that, and am controlling things with udev and fstab.

Comment: Can you expand a little on this? Curious minds want to know :-) I don't see any setting like that in Nautilus File Manager. Are you using something else? What did you do with udev and fstab?

Comment: I followed instructions on a post here to change to Thunar some time ago.

Comment: Ah, that's why I didn't know about that option. That's not a standard out of the box configuration. I know what you did with fstab. What did you do with udev?

Comment: I added a standard udev rule to auto-mount USB drives...

Comment: I thought that you didn't want auto-mount? Wasn't that the whole point?

Comment: I wanted one particular drive, by UUID, to not auto-mount.  I want my other USB media to auto-mount.  Now that works.

Comment: The other drive should have auto-mounted without having to create a udev rule... you could have just added it to fstab. The other answer just addressed your desire not to auto-mount that recovered drive. So with the exception of the Thunar thing, my fstab answer was correct, yes?

Comment: I deseleted automatically mounting external drives in Thunar, so I had to enable it elsewhere.  I didn't test whether disabling volume management in Thunar would result in USB drives being auto-mounted - maybe they would be anyway.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need a udev rule to mount that other drive. Even with Thunar's option is disabled, just adding a normal entry into fstab should work. A part of the point that I'm trying to make is... that without disclosure of Thunar, my other answer was correct and complete, yes?

Comment: I accepted your answer to the other question about this I posted, as your mount command works.  --  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199318/how-to-block-automounting-of-a-specific-drive-usb-connection-with-three-mou

Comment: Thanks! You know how to add the mount entries into fstab, yes. Then you can remove the udev rule. Cheers!